# How to Know Schema Before Unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

**Scenario:**

I am trying to refactor a code, which asks user to choose an xml file, which suppose to adhere to any of the 2 given schemas. Right now, the code is trying to unmarshal it using `Schema A Unmarshaller`. If that fails it is trying to unmarshal it using `Schema B Unmarshaller`. In case both fails it is rejecting the file by displaying a proper message to the user.

**Problem:**

Here the program flow depends on `Exception` thrown by `unmarshal()`.

**Question:**

Is there any way to know by which `unmarshaller` we should attempt to parse the file, so we go for the correct unmarshaller right away? Further, this would also help us in rejecting all irrelevant XML files, which doesn't conform to either schemas.

Comment: Of course, we can read the file, like any other file, but I am looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different options:

**Option #1 - Create the JAXBContext on Multiple Domain Models**

If the models for the two schemas are compatible (are completely independent, or share types that are annotated the same way), then just create the JAXBContext on all of the domain objects instead of having one per schema.

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

**Option #2 - StAX Input**

If having different XML schemas means having different root elements I would create a StAX XMLStreamReader look at the root element and then choose which marshaller to use.  Then unmarshal that XMLStreamReader.

**Option #3 - Validate the XML Document First**

You could use the javax.xml.validation APIs to validate the document first and then based on the results choose the unmarshaller.

Comment: +1 You know, actually, I was waiting for you because I know you got a good command on XML parsers and JAXB. Will let you know about it. Right now thinking about whether to use JAXB generated class as a root node of JTree, or use `DefaultMutableTreeNode` and maintain actual POJO simultaneously with that as a `userObject`.

Comment: Doing it with the second option. Once again thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should look at using a SAX parser and process the two structures manually in one handler. Another possibility is to create a new schema that allows the two options.

If I had complete control of the schemas I would look at the second option. If the response schemas were simple and/or shared a similar structure I would look at using SAX.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I would try the second option. If that doesn't work, even then I believe I would be able to use the SAX parser, if not completely but at least to check the first element. +1